# how count different elements of a column?

Tags: pyspark

Hi I am wondering how I can count elements of each row in the whole data set?
I have the following column:

```
col
(‘a’, ‘b’),(‘a’, ‘c’),(‘b’, ‘c’)
(‘g’, ‘h’),(‘a’, ‘c’),(‘a’, ‘b’)
```

I wanna count how many of the above pair exist in the data set!

```
Output:
(‘a’, ‘b’)  2
(‘a’, ‘c’). 2
(‘b’, ‘c’).  1
(‘g’, ‘h’).  1
```

I know in pandas I can do this:

```
h=data['col'].str.findall(r'(\([^()]+\))').explode().value_counts()
```

Comment: hm, if you "count elements of each row", then `('a', 'b')` suppose to be 1 not 2?

Comment: not each row. in whole rows. the second row also have ('a','b')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your input data is a string (based on your regex), I'd suggest changing the middle comma by another separator, which you can use to split later. I'm using pipe here for demo purpose only, you can change to another unique pattern.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = (spark
    .sparkContext
    .parallelize([
        ("('a', 'b'),('a', 'c'),('b', 'c')",),
        ("('g', 'h'),('a', 'c'),('a', 'b')",),
    ])
    .toDF(['col'])
)

# Output
# +--------------------------------+
# |col                             |
# +--------------------------------+
# |('a', 'b'),('a', 'c'),('b', 'c')|
# |('g', 'h'),('a', 'c'),('a', 'b')|
# +--------------------------------+

(df
    .withColumn('col', F.regexp_replace('col', '\),\(', ')|('))
    .withColumn('col', F.explode(F.split('col', '\|')))
    .groupBy('col')
    .count()
    .show(10, False)
)

# Output
# +----------+-----+
# |col       |count|
# +----------+-----+
# |('g', 'h')|1    |
# |('a', 'c')|2    |
# |('b', 'c')|1    |
# |('a', 'b')|2    |
# +----------+-----+
```

Comment: I found an easy way: just explode and then count